# Draw a shape over an image in android

Tags: android

[image]

I'd like to draw a shape like the orange rectangle in the attached image in android and i have no idea how to.

Comment: Doing this dynamically in Android is a bit complicated. You would need to create a custom View and override the onDraw method to draw your shape. But you need to know the size of the image (and if there is text on the image you don't want to cover up you would need to know where that is located). I would recommend extending ImageView and in the onDraw method call super.onDraw then draw your custom shape.

Answer (score 0):

It's a few steps to do this. A good start could be to read about the Canvas object: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html